# Getting no-name-in-module on pylint when having duplicates names

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, pylint

My current folder structure is something like this:

```
folder/
   utils.py
   something.py
   etc.py
```

In something.py I do some imports:

```
from folder.etc import x
import utils.some_module
```

*utils* is a package installed from pip that unfortunately has the same name as one of my files inside *folder*. The code works normally but for some reason pylint gives me this error:

```
folder/something.py:11: [import-error(pylint), None] Unable to import 'utils.some_module'
folder/something.py:11: [no-name-in-module(pylint), None] No name 'some_module' in module 'utils'
```

If I change the file name from utils.py to something else the error disappears but I don't want to change it. The structure of package utils is as follow:

```
utils/
  __init__.py
  some_module
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem without changing the file name?

Thanks

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: Thanks bhaskar but python is able to execute my code without any problem, the problem is with pylint raising no-name-in-module even though the code works.